# Lotus-Notes Agent: Recover only the files from the current email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Currently in my agent, I browse my email files like this:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

    Dim myServer As String
    Dim myMailfile As String

    myServer = <server>
    myMailfile = <mailfile>
    ' *** Open the specified mail file using back-end classes
    Set db = New NotesDatabase(myServer, myMailfile)
    
    If Not (db Is Nothing) Then
        Set view = db.GETVIEW("$Inbox")
        If Not (view Is Nothing) Then
            Call view.Refresh
            Set doc = view.GETFIRSTDOCUMENT
            Do While Not doc Is Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set item = doc.GETFIRSTITEM("Body")
                If doc.HasEmbedded Then
                    item.EmbeddedObjects
                    ForAll attachment In item.EmbeddedObjects
                        Call attachment.ExtractFile ("C:\Users\admin\Documents\files\" & attachment.Name)
                    End ForAll
                End If
                Set doc = view.GETNEXTDOCUMENT(doc)
            Loop
        End If
    End If
```

But it will recover all the files present in my emails. Whereas I would like to recover only the files from the current email (the email I selected). Is it possible to do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hint: Look at the UnprocessedDocuments property of NotesDatabase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the agent properties you can set up what the "target" of an agent is. By default it is "selected documents". The "target" is made available to the agent using the "UnprocessedDocuments"- Property of the NotesDatabase- Object.

```
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase '- get the database where the agent runs
Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()
While not doc is Nothing
    '- here comes the inner code from your own while loop
    Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
```

Just one thing: item.EmbeddedObjects will NOT get all attachments of your mails. It may fail for attachments in MIME- Mails.

If you really want to get ALL attachments, regardless of the origin / type of mail you should use the @AttachmentNames(0) - Workaround:

```
Dim arrAttachments as Variant
Dim embObj as NotesEmbeddedObject

arrAttachments = Evaluate( "@Attachmentnames(0)" )
Forall strAttachment in arrAttachments
  Set embObj = doc.GetAttachment(strAttachment)
  Call embObj.ExtractFile ("C:\Users\admin\Documents\files\" & embObj.Name)
End Forall
```